# Healpy installation failure

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-venv, healpy

I am trying to install healpy in a venv I created. I successfully installed numpy and astropy but when i run the following:

```
pip install healpy
```

or

```
pip install -U healpy
```

the installation fails with a very long message, which starts with some

```
UserWarning: Unknown Extension options: 'cython_directives'
```

and ends with a RED text ending in:

```
failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/bp/bvhb5c9n54n0pyyf6694m_z80000gn/T/pip-install-fvug_ld0/healpy/
```

can somebody help me correctly installing healpy in my venv?

Comment: Just to clarify, is this specific to when you are trying to install health into your venv or does this happen for all pip installs?

Comment: Are you running on Linux/Mac?

Comment: Are you using conda?

Comment: @MattB. OSX 10.13.6

Comment: @K.Maj No I have not installed conda in my venv and I'd prefer not to do so

Comment: @JackMoody yes it is specific to healpy, I successfully installed numpy and astropy in my venv.

Comment: Update: pip install healpy==1.10.2 installed healpy, but pip install --user --upgrade healpy crashed in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured I'd post my solution here since a better one is lacking.

```
pip install healpy==1.10.2
```

and

```
pip install healpy==1.10.3
```

worked and successfully installed the respective version of healpy in my venv.

For some reason more recent versions result in the error mentioned in the question.